# jquery how to skip "a" element if its array value is null

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Could you please help on how can I achieve not show "a" only if "a1links" value is null.

ie.for the second value on "a1links" array;I dont want "ahref" link to be shown on my html page.

```
    var a1links = [ 
        '8li ', '',
'8li ', 'a1link4-',
'a1link5-', 'a1link6-',

...
<a data-name="'+ a1links[j] + imageName +'" href="">'+ a1links[j] + imageName + '</a><br>
```

but for only values with "null" or '  ' be skipped,The others need to continue as they are.

the complete function is

```
$.each( images, function( j, imageName ) {           

$('<div class="card">                                                                                                                          <a data-name="'+ alinks[j] + imageName +'" href="www"><img data-name="'+ imageName +'" src="'+ pathPrefix + imageName +'-button-1'+'.jpg" alt="'+ imageName +'"></a>                                                                                                                                <div id="cardbodydiv">                                                                                                                            <h5 id="titlecard">'+ alinks[j] + imageName +'</h5>                                                                                                <p id="textcard">                                                                                                                                   <a data-name="'+ a1links[j] + imageName +'" href="">'+ a1links[j] + imageName + '</a><br>                                                           <a data-name="'+ a2links[j] + imageName +'" href="">'+ a2links[j] + imageName + '</a>                                                            </p>                                                                                                                                                 </div></div>').appendTo('#images');                    
                                });
```

thanks a lot for helping.

-------------------------what I tried is below -----------------
this is removing the "a" for all if a1links array is completely empty....

```
$("input[name='a1links[]']").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value) {
        a1links.push(value);
    }
});
if (a1links.length === 0) {
  $(".test").hide();
    }

else {
  //send data
}
```

but I only require this if one of the value on the array is empty.the other array values needs to be read by function and create  of a1links

```
    $.each( images, function( j, imageName ) {           

$('<div class="card">                                                                                                                          <a data-name="'+ alinks[j] + imageName +'" href="www"><img data-name="'+ imageName +'" src="'+ pathPrefix + imageName +'-button-1'+'.jpg" alt="'+ imageName +'"></a>                                                                                                                                <div id="cardbodydiv">                                                                                                                            <h5 id="titlecard">'+ alinks[j] + imageName +'</h5>                                                                                                <p id="textcard">                                                                                                                                   <a id="a1links" class ="test" a data-name="'+ a1links[j] + imageName +'" href="">'+ a1links[j] + imageName + '</a><br>                                              <a data-name="'+ a2links[j] + imageName +'" href="">'+ a2links[j] + imageName + '</a>                                                            </p>                                                                                                                                                 </div></div>').appendTo('#images');                    
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a1links = [ 
        '8li ', '',
'8li ', 'a1link4-',
'a1link5-', 'a1link6-']

let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
a1links.forEach(link => {
 if(link) { // all truthy values
   let a_tag = document.createElement("a")
  a_tag.href = link
  a_tag.innerText = `${link} | `
  fragment.appendChild(a_tag)
 }
})

document.body.appendChild(fragment)
```

Here's a snippet in javascript to achieve the same